# Implementing a convolution reverb with rapidly updated impulse responses

Tags: javascript, signal-processing, web-audio-api

i'm doing my master thesis on acoustic raytracing, using WebGL as access point to the GPU horsepower and WebAudio to drive the soundcard. Let's assume, the raytracer is implemented such that it delivers an updated impulse response every frame while a graphics rendering engine runs at 30 frames per second. So a room is displayed on screen and one can move in that room with realtime graphics and acoustic informations.

I understand that the impulse response (IR) as well as the audio signal (x) to be played have to be splitted in blocks for circular convolution. This needs to be extended to a dynamic convolution kernel.

Now comes a puzzling part: a sound block of the audio signal x that is started in the current frame begins with the current IR. In the next frame, an updated IR is available, so a part of this new IR needs to be convolved with the first block of x (because it still rings in that room), and also the second block of x must be convolved with the beginning of the new IR. (Illustration will follow soon)

The framework runs in the browser (Chrome), so this convolution stuff needs to be done in javascript. I'm new to WebAudio, but since the support for AudioWorkers is still outstanding, i will need to implement it in some other way. Since this is a heavy processing task, has anyone an idea for solving this in javascript to render the audio chain in realtime?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Until Audio Workers come online to add thread(s) to Web Audio, the single threaded nature of browser javascript strictly limits any real time heavy lifting - I experienced this when I tasked the browser to render using Web Audio while negotiating Web Socket traffic with a Node.js server to provide streaming audio - since solved using a Web Worker (WW) - look-up the flavor of WW called Transferable Objects which permits transferring **HUGE** typed arrays to/from WW - I can post an example usage if need be just give a shout ... good luck

Comment: Thanks. My supervisor and i decided to leave out this heavy processing part for now and just update once per second. Do you have an info about when audio workers will be realized in browsers? I'm also experimenting with WebWorkers in a ScriptProcessorNode, but it clicks all the time. I'd like to see your solution, because i'm afraid i messed something up with the transferables. Greetings, Thomas

Comment: My code is on github available from https://www.npmjs.com/package/websockets-streaming-audio

Comment: Thanks, Scott. This runs WebAudio in the main thread, isn't it?

Comment: Yes it runs Web Audio in the browser thread which makes calls to Web Workers using Transferable Objects for calls to Node.js using Web Socket ... if that wasn't enough take a peek at a similar project where I throw WebGL into the mix to visualize Web Audio in time domain and frequency domain  : https://www.npmjs.com/package/webgl-3d-animation    on this one go full screen F11, hit button play jam looped and use keys w/a/s/d arrows left/right/up/down and page up/down plus mouse left button + middle scroll wheel ...  PS. that project was my hello world for javascript so don't judge me ;-)  enjoy

Comment: Thanks. I've looked into it, but recently i've decided to stop working on this task. The new sceme will be splitting the impulse response into an more often updated early reflection part and a diffuse reverberation part, both implemented as convolverNodes. I've also tried to emulate early reflections with some dozens of delayNodes, but that was too much for my machine in the long run. Anyway, thanks for the help:)